# Selecting an element by its data-id attribute not working on all elements

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to select an element by its data-id attribute.
The issue is that it is not working across all elements for some reason.
For some reason, the script below will only work on items under the Rotor-Stator category and no other.

Here is a sample of the HTML

```
<div class="prodCat">
  <button class="accordion prodCat even">Rotor-Stator Homogenizers</button>
  <div class="panel" id="rshom">
    <div class="item catlink" data-id="391">Tissue Master</div>
    <div class="item catlink" data-id="390">TH Tissue Homogenizer</div>
    <div class="item catlink" data-id="480">Micro Homogenizer</div>
    <div class="item catlink" data-id="481">THQ Digital Tissue Homogenizer</div>
    <div class="item catlink" data-id="395">GLH General Laboratory Homogenizer</div>
    <div class="item catlink" data-id="396">Mixer Homogenizer</div>
  </div>
  <button class="item prodCat" data-id="103" ">Automated Homogenizers</button>
  <button class="item prodCat even " data-id="108 ">Bead Mill Homogenizers</button>
  <button class="accordion prodCat ">Bead Mill Nucleic Acid Extractor</button>
  <div class="panel " id="bmnae ">
    <div class="item catlink " data-id="489 ">DNA Purification</div>
    <div class="item catlink " data-id="490 ">RNA Purification</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Jquery:

This works

```
$('.prodCatCol').find(".item[data-id='391']").css('background', 'red');
```

This Does NOT work

```
$('.prodCatCol').find(".item[data-id='489']").css('background', 'red');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `<button class="item prodCat" data-id="103" ">Automated Homogenizers</button>` repeat quotes break HTML, ensure this is not the cause   ------^-- before posting the code.

Comment: I also had a space after each id number too. I removed the spaces and removed the extra quote and it fixed it. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unique identifier in your data-ID's for values 489 & 490 contain a space character. These data-id's are treated as strings and not integers.

So one option: Remove the spaces from the Data-id's

```
 <div class="panel " id="bmnae ">
      <div class="item catlink " data-id="489">DNA Purification</div>
      <div class="item catlink " data-id="490">RNA Purification</div>
</div>
```

Also, you have inconsisten HTML markup for example in the line with `data-id="103" "`
Those 3 double quotes will give you markup issues.

Comment: Thank you, the spaces where the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well because `data-id="489 "` has space in it just like a few others. Also format your HTML much more otherwise you're up for more problems!

Answer (score 1):

You have left space in data-id = "489 " and have added an added quotes on line 11.

Replace given html with it then try:

```
<div class="prodCat">
  <button class="accordion prodCat even">Rotor-Stator Homogenizers</button>
  <div class="panel" id="rshom">
    <div class="item catlink" data-id="391">Tissue Master</div>
    <div class="item catlink" data-id="390">TH Tissue Homogenizer</div>
    <div class="item catlink" data-id="480">Micro Homogenizer</div>
    <div class="item catlink" data-id="481">THQ Digital Tissue Homogenizer</div>
    <div class="item catlink" data-id="395">GLH General Laboratory Homogenizer</div>
    <div class="item catlink" data-id="396">Mixer Homogenizer</div>
  </div>
  <button class="item prodCat" data-id="103">Automated Homogenizers</button>
  <button class="item prodCat even " data-id="108">Bead Mill Homogenizers</button>
  <button class="accordion prodCat ">Bead Mill Nucleic Acid Extractor</button>
  <div class="panel " id="bmnae ">
    <div class="item catlink " data-id="489">DNA Purification</div>
    <div class="item catlink " data-id="490">RNA Purification</div>
  </div>
</div>
```